# How to use AutoMapper to define a single map for a duplicate class name in multiple namespaces?

Tags: automapper

Given two maps that only differ in destination type:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<System.Exception, GeneratedNamespace1.ErrorMessage>().
  ForAllMembers(/* some mapping */);
Mapper.CreateMap<System.Exception, GeneratedNamespace2.ErrorMessage>().
  ForAllMembers(/* identical mapping as above */ );
```

How can this code be simplified to a single mapping setup?

The goal is to resolve the ErrorMessage type by class name only, instead of by fully qualified name.

Notes:

- Using AutoMapper version 2.1.267.0.
- The GeneratedNamespace1/2 duplication exists due to code generation (XSD.EXE or web service references)

Comment: If ErrorMessage is the same type, why is it in 2 places ?

Comment: The different ErorrMessage types are generated due to code generation (XSD.EXE or web service references).  They have the same properties.

For the sake of this question, the assumption is that this cannot be changed.